# When we use source in rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database

I have simple question, When we use `source` in our relationships ans what is meant by source.

For example

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Person'
   has_many :children, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :parent_id
   has_many :grandchildren, class_name: 'Person', through: :children, source: :children
end
```

Assume above example and guide me with simple answer

Comment: Can anyone answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as the second link in your association. Say you have three tables A, B, C. You want to associate A to C, and will need to go through B. So A => B => C where B is the through table, C would be the source. Going the opposite direction A <= B <= C, B is again the through table but A is now the source.

Comment: When we are going opposite then we have to mention source? - right?

Comment: @UzmaManzor yes source is needed in both directions

Comment: But i think has_may through not require source every time. I have done many time. But this time i have to mention source.

Comment: Thanks for your time.